# Java-Maven: How to add manually a library to the maven repository?

Tags: maven-2

I'm trying to generate a jasperReport, but I receive this:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Times New Roman' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
```

After searching on the net, I found that I need to add a jar to the classpath with the font. So, I create a jar file with the ttf files and now I want to add this as a dependency to my pom file.

So: I installed the file :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=tf.jar -DgroupId=tf -DartifactId=tf -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and in my pom, I added these lines:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>tf</groupId>
            <artifactId>tf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

but I receive this: `Dependency 'tf:tf:1.0.0' not found less`

I checked the repository folder and the jar file is there, in ... tf\tf\1.0.0\

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the command used to install your 3rd party jar looks identical to [the reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) (I would just also generate a pom by adding `-DgeneratePom=true`), the snippet to declare the dependency in your pom looks fine. What you're doing seems ok.

Could you provide the exact trace?

Comment: @Aaron Glad it's working (I don't think that not having a pom was blocking though).